# I need to allocate physical swapspace on termux on android to use dotnet

Tags: android, .net, linux, termux

I am using Termux on a pixel 7a. In termux I have installed ubuntu using proot.

In ubuntu I've installed dotnet-runtime-7.0

When I run:

dotnet -h

I get the error:

GC heap initialization failed with error 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E

This error indicates that I am out of memory.

I closed all apps besides termux and I ran htop. It said I have 1.4 gb of free memory and 1.2 gb of free system swap.

My question is I want to know how to take a linux system like termux on android and create some swap and force the dotnet command to run in that swapspace.

I need it in order to do some dotnet development on android.

I tried installing ubuntu on termud via proot then I installed the latest stable dotnet command from the ubuntu package repository. Then I ran dotnet -h

I got an error saying that I was out of memory. This is concerning because some if the best android devices on the market only have 12 gb of ram. This makes it problematic to develop dotnet on android.

Comment: It is entirely unclear *why* you would spend any time on something like this.  You're running a virtual machine (.net) inside of an O/S (Ubuntu) inside of a virtual machine (Android VM) inside of an O/S (Linux / Android).  You are likely the only person on the planet trying to do so.

Comment: Swap is below the level of termux and proot. You will have to do it directly on Android, which afaik requires a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use it directly in Termux without proot with help of the patched [glibc for Termux?](https://github.com/termux-pacman/glibc-packages) maybe it will work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35462225)